# div layout resizing query

Tags: html, css

This is quite a basic issue but I've put together a site that was looking fine until I went to add another part to it and now the layout doesn't quite work properly. The principle is the same as the code I've just put inserted. So my header, `navbar` and footer have a fixed height and the content fills the rest of the space left, but if the content exceeds the height of the browser, rather than push the footer down, it just overlaps. What is the correct way to do this? I've used relative rather than absolute positioning which is OK until the content is less than the browser height so the footer moves halfway up the page.

Thanks in advance.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding:  0;
}
#header {
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  background:red;
}
#nav {
  position: absolute;
  top:40px;
  width:100%;
  height:25px;
  background:blue;
}
#content {
  position: absolute;
  top:65px;
  bottom:40px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:yellow;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="nav"></div>
<div id="content">
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-height` on `#content`, like:

```
#content {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 105px); /* Total window height minus the #nav, #header & #footer height */
}
```

Have a look at the working snippet below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding:  0;
}
#header {
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  background:red;
}
#nav {
  top:40px;
  width:100%;
  height:25px;
  background:blue;
}
#content {
  top:65px;
  bottom:40px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:yellow;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 105px);
}
#footer {
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="nav"></div>
<div id="content">
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this, works really well with text content. Im having an issue with displaying a mysql result though, its just overlapping the footer div rather than pushing it down, I tried using overflow but it either masks it or adds a scroller to the div which I dont want. Any ideas?

Comment: @JeffSimons Can you please post the code so that I can understand your problem better?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you apply position: fixed for header nav and footer so that those elements will always stay in the same position on browser. Then the content can the static positioned and it will be adjusting based on the content. Please check your code with some minor changes.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding:  0;
}
#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  background:red;
}
#nav {
  position: fixed;
  top:40px;
  width:100%;
  height:25px;
  background:blue;
}
#content {
  width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  background:yellow;
  margin: 65px 0 40px;
}
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="nav"></div>
<div id="content">
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
text here.....<br>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```